# How can I save a sound clip that a website loads in a JavaScript player?

Tags: music, web

I really like the music clip that loads in the JavaScript-based player [here](http://www.audiodraft.com/sourcing/contests/contest.php?id=123#entries&eid=9538). How can I save it to my computer?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Perhaps you could download it from here.</strike> (Expired link is expired.)

I used Google Chrome's Developer Tools to find a link to the mp3.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools]

Comment: The access keys are obviously temporarily created for the AJAX request. Link doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, boo. Let's try again.